# Function extract() from date returns double precision value

Tags: postgresql, functions, date-format

Why does the Postgres function `extract()` return `double precision` from `date` value?

Only reason I could imagine is, there are some locales using calendars (those not Gregorian calendars and supported by Postgres), calculate date/time differently and possible return float number.

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA: Postgres is a perfectly valid alternative name for PostgreSQL.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name OK I can rollback

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA: no need to rollback.

Answer (score 5):

Because the return values can be large or a decimal number.
 
Double precision will accept a wide range of values

Looking at other numeric types, you only have decimal which will have overhead:  you don't know the return scale or precision needed beforehand so it would have to wide

```
SELECT EXTRACT(SECOND FROM TIME '17:12:28.5');
Result: 28.5

SELECT EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE '2001-02-16 20:38:40.12-08');
Result: 982384720.12
```

See [PG docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT)

Comment: Well, i did'nt think about seconds. I was thinking about month or year field. It can't be fractional. Does it?

Comment: @simar: Not sure to be honest. Never tried it.. but I think not

Answer (score 3):

You can always cast the result of `extract`.

```
SELECT EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM TIMESTAMP '2001-02-16 20:38:40')::integer;
```

That way you always get an integer.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: I'm curious about why the downvote as well. While this doesn't answer the question of "why", it seems like a reasonable response to the question.

Comment: This rounds the value. If you need to truncate it, use `SELECT TRUNC(EXTRACT(SECOND FROM TIMESTAMP '2001-02-16 20:38:29.6'))`

Answer (score 1):

Even if extracting fields from a date would always produce results that could fit in an integer, according to the [doc](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT), `extract` doesn't directly  work on a `date` type:

> The extract function retrieves subfields such as year or hour from
>   date/time values. source must be a value expression of type
>   **timestamp, time, or interval**. (Expressions of type date are cast to timestamp and can therefore be used as well.)

So `extract(date...)` does not exist as such, rather it's `extract(timestamp...)` with an implicit cast of the argument, and `extract(timestamp...)` can't return only integers, for instance `extract(seconds from timestamp)` has a fractional part.

In addition to that, `extract(epoch from date)` doesn't fit in a postgres integer for dates beyond the `19 January 2038` (see [The Year 2038 problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem)), which will be become a real problem as we progress towards that date.